# How would I solve an error converting bytecode in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I find a problem using ionic 3, I try to run 'ionic cordova run android' but error, this is error that I get :

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:(Main.java:775)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
```

and this is my ionic info :
[geMpF.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeMpF.png)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the result of `java --version` and `gradle --version`

Comment: @christoandrew my JDK version is 1.8.0_73 and my gradle version is 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

try add dexOptions in your gradel file and also change the compileOptions

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"


    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```